# Why set request object values with JInput->set in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I was looking at joomla code of a controller and I came across this function.

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
   {
      JRequest::setVar('view', 'categories');
       parent::display();
    }
```

what is the purpose of setting values  of request object.The view can be set through 
controller's getView() function.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

`getView()` is not setting the actual view.  It's getting it. This code is setting the value in the request.  In particular this would be useful for setting the default view if no view was present in the request. Also, `JRequest` is deprecated, so that code is legacy code (as is `getView()`.